# Question about Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning/practicing Regex. I've written this to test for url's...I want it to catch url's in these formats:

```
www.site.com
www.site.co.uk etc
site.com
play.site.com
```

So I've written this:

```
(http:\/\/)*(www)*\.*(\w{2,})(\.{1})(\w{2,3})(\.*)(\w{2,3})*
```

(match http:// 0 or more times, followed by some more characters 0 or more times, followed by a domain name, followed by a period, followed by some more characters (at least 2, max 3), then followed by an optional period and some more chars (for co.uk etc).)

I'm very new to regex so not sure if there's problems with what i've done but it seems to work well in testing here: http://regexpal.com/ . Feel free to rip it apart!

The one thing I've noticed is that it does match .site.com which I don't want. How can I match just site.com and still allow for http:// and www and subdomains?

Comment: You might want to check out the ? operator -- I don't think you really want to match the http:// or www multiple times.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That's very useful...same as {0,1} right?

Comment: Your examples are not URLs, they're hostnames, and hostnames are impractical to spot in general text because any word or dot-separated sequence of words is a valid hostname. Saying anything with (dot)(two or three letters) at the end is a hostname is perilous as you will catch both many false positive, *and* fail to match any of the TLDs that aren't 2-3 letters long. I would not attempt to match hostnames in text; better to require users to be explicit and type the `http://`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the "." in the "www" match; that will resolve the problem of potentially having a leading dot matching in your url.

Answer (score 1):

Please please don't use this code in anything serious.  Parsing URIs with regexps is wrong and horrible - use a library to do it properly.

Comment: I agree that there are better ways, but why is it "wrong"? As far as I can tell, the set of valid URIs is a regular language.

Comment: Surely a library uses regex? What better ways are there?

Comment: @Platinum Azure - because you will almost certainly get the regexp wrong.  URIs have a lot more forms/structures than most people realise, so the odds are that a homebrew regexp will be buggy.  For example, dealing with # fragments, ? parameters, usernames, passwords and different url schemas makes this very non-trivial

Comment: @Malcolm Box: I suppose I must have misunderstood you. To me, (X)HTML/XML parsing with regex is "wrong" because those are context-free languages. A URI, while difficult to get exactly right, does not have that limitation-- the components of a URL are generally very well ordered. Also, sometimes you don't WANT certain components of a URI-- how often do you use username/password, for example? So IF YOU'RE CAREFUL, I don't see anything particularly wrong with it. But I have no issue with the claim that there are far better methods out there.

Comment: Isn't this the only way supported by mod_rewrite? I'm tempted to down vote this... Asker said he's practicing...